# How to enter value in a textbox through Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to enter a word in a browser through scripting/automation. Here is the snippet:

```
        <div id="id1" class="class1" 
                      hidefocus="true" 
                      aria-label="Message Body" 
                      g_editable="true" 
                      role="textbox" 
                      aria-multiline="true" 
                      contenteditable="true" 
                      tabindex="1" 
                      spellcheck="true">
```

In this textbox, how can I enter some text like "Hello World" using dispatchEvent? I understand this is not an input element where I can just write document.getElementbyId("id1").value='Hello World'. I have to tackle this through dispatchEvent i suppose but I am having trouble doing so.

Comment: your snippet shows a `div` not a `textarea`

Comment: `document.getElementbyId("id1").innerText='Hello World'` OR `document.getElementbyId("id1").innerHTML='Hello World'` should suffice.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use dispatchEvent?

Comment: I thought I HAD to use dispatchEvent as this was a div - i wasn't sure about it though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

document.getElementbyId("id1").innerText='Hello World

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using CustomEvent, which is described in more detail at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

```
<div
    id="id1"
    class="class1" 
    hidefocus="true" 
    aria-label="Message Body" 
    g_editable="true" 
    role="textbox" 
    aria-multiline="true" 
    contenteditable="true" 
    tabindex="1" 
    spellcheck="true">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let event = new CustomEvent('sayHelloWorld', { detail: 'Hello, World!' });
    let id1Div = document.getElementById("id1");

    id1Div.addEventListener('sayHelloWorld', function (e) {
      id1Div.innerText = e.detail;
    }, false);

    id1Div.dispatchEvent(event);
</script>
```